# Is the standard deviation affected by using calibration weights?

Tags: estimation, standard-deviation, weights

I'm sorry if the terminology is incorrect. I have tried to find some background information through standard google searches, but I've come up short.

I work with data from a quesionnaire on health issues. Through a couple of manipulation, each answer/set of answers is converted to a dichotomous variable, where 1 codes for prescence of the variable in question (good health, bad health, risky gambling habits etc). This lets us calculate which proportion of our sample has got bad health etc.

We're not satisfied with simply taking a random sample. Since we might have sampled individuals not representative of the population at large in respect to certain background variables (education, income, citizinship etc), so each observation is weighted according to these variables (using some kind of complicated procedure). This yieldes a so called calibration weight, which is used in the following way to calculate proportions:

$$\hat{Y}=\frac{\sum{w_iy_i}}{\sum{w_i}} $$

Where $w$ is the calibration weight of the observation $i$ and $y$ is its variable value.

Now to my question:

Does this weighting process also affect the way I should calculate my standard deviations, and in that case how?

This has mostly been done automatically "behind the scenes" until now, but I will have to do ut explicitly/manually in order to simplify our code. This topic was not covered in my undergraduate statistics classes and not hinted at in our documentation.

Comment: It does affect how you calculate standard errors. Unfortunately, it's not simple to specify one way which SEs are calculated. This is because the way you estimate error depends upon the survey design. For example, a simple random survey which has been weighted with a single post-stratum has an approximate formula for variance (for example, equation 4.22 in Lohr's "Sampling" book). With complex e.g. multistage (multiple levels of clustering), a easy way to calculate standard errors is to use a Delete-a Group Jacknife (Kott 2001), which gives one formula to calculate basically any SE.

Comment: What's your survey design? I am guessing that the weighting of observations is something like RIM weighting?

Comment: @AlexJ The last time I delved into this it had something to do with GREG estimators or something like that....

Comment: @AlexJ

The weighting is done behind the scenes in PROC SUMMARY with SAS without us specifying any options. Therefore it "should" default to ordinary wald confidence intervals I think...

Comment: @AlexJ All right, but the standard deviation is calculated as sqrt(p(1-p)) if memory serves me correctly. Do I used the p for my sample here, or the estimated p (from using the weights) for the entire population?

Comment: @AlexJ Supposedly we're using Simple Random Samplng, I checked.

Comment: Being an SRS will make your life easier. Unfortunately, I don't know a formula off the top of my head. You might want to search for things like "variance of raking / GREG estimator". Alternatively, you could use a bootstrap, which should be simple to implement.

Comment: @AlexJ Okay, thanks. Is there some kind of recommended textbook for this kind of question?

Comment: Sharon Lohr's _Sampling: Design and Analysis_ might be a good start. In particular, I think Section 9.3.3. "The Bootstrap" could be useful.